# Is there any way to hide the connection string on my MySQL Backup Restore code?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have these code to backup and restore mysql from vb application.

These are my codes:

```
Dim DBFILE As String

        Try
            OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "SQL Dump File (*.sql)|*.sql|All files (*.*)|*.*"
            If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                DBFILE = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                Dim BackupProcess As New Process
                BackupProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
                BackupProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                BackupProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\"
                BackupProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
                BackupProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
                BackupProcess.Start()

                Dim BackupStream As StreamWriter = BackupProcess.StandardInput
                Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader = BackupProcess.StandardOutput
                BackupStream.WriteLine("mysql --user=" & dbUser & " --password=" & dbPassword & " -h " & dbServer & " " & dbName & " < """ + DBFILE + """")

                BackupStream.Close()
                BackupProcess.WaitForExit()
                BackupProcess.Close()
                MsgBox("Restore succesfully", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Restore info")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

When i executed these codes in my application, a command prompt window opened like this:
[Command Prompt shown when Backup and Restore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klhMA.png)

> At the title bar, it clearly shown my connection string.
>
> 1. The user
> 2. The password
> 3. The server name
> 4. The database name
>
> How do i hide this string or any idea to not show this command prompt
>   window?

Thanks in advance for give some attention and helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set another option:

```
BackupProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
```

Alternatively, can you specify the conn str as a command line argument for a different result?

Comment: That was a great solution! Thank you @Caius. For the con string in the title bar, i don't know how to encrypt it when it shown in the command prompt. But your solution is perfect for me.